# Objects not getting freed/destroyed but Allocations Instrument says retain count is at 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I'm cleaning up my project and when I run it in the Allocations Instrument the reference count goes down to 0 but it's never getting destroyed. Is there something I'm missing here in my clean up?

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject *subParser;
```

.m

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
    didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
    qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"NewParser"]) {
        MySubParser *aParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] init];
        self.subParser = aParser;
        [aParser release];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
    didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
    qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"NewParser"]) {
        [self.subParser release];
        subParser = nil;
    }
}

- (void) dealloc {
    self.subParser = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

edit: corrected @property declaration in .h

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. The fix was to ONLY call **`self.subParser = nil;`** in the **`-didEndElement`** and remove the self.subParser = nil from the dealloc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment in the code below fixed it. Instead of the retain count going to 0 it was cleaned from the heap.

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject *subParser;
```

.m

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
    didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
    qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"NewParser"]) {
        MySubParser *aParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] init];
        self.subParser = aParser;
        [aParser release];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
    didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
    qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"NewParser"]) {
        [self.subParser release];
        subParser = nil;  //FIXED by changing to self.subParser = nil;
    }
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why in the .h the property is called "parser" and you use this like "self.subParser"?

You can have some problem if you have a function param that have the same name of the property (you should get a warning from the compiler) because the param "hide" the property. Please check this naming stuff

Answer (score 0):

You might want:

```
- (void) dealloc {
    if (subParser) 
       [subParser release], subParser = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

You're just setting the properly to nil won't release it.

Also retain count isn't really reliable.

Comment: It sets the property. As it's declared as «retain», the previous object will receive a release message. SO that's not the solution.

Comment: also, you don't need the if. You can message nil objects.

Comment: Yes i don't put a lot of stock in retain counts. In the allocations instrument it notes the autoreleases as well so at least you get a general idea of where everything is going.

Comment: If the subParser is already released and you try to release it again won't it crash? The OP's code could have a situation where subParser is never retained.

Comment: It looks like I found the issue. The `@property` is being retained so when I set the object via the `self.` accessor it's being held on to by objective-c's internals. By just using the accessor method to set to nil is all that's needed for it to be freed. So in the `-didEndElement` method I set `self.subParser = nil;` (without the [self.subParser release] call). I also removed it from the dealloc since it's not needed after the didEndElement. In the Allocations Instrument the live bytes show 0 and # overall is showing the count of instances.